# Having issues opening up a port for my instance on GCE

Tags: firewall, connection

I'm running a GCE instance. I ran `sudo ufw allow http && nc -l 80` and it succeeds, showing that 80 is open. However, when I try to open up a server by running waitress, a Python server, with `sudo waitress-serve --listen=0.0.0.0:80 --call 'flaskr:create_app'`, it doesn't work. I made sure that the firewalls set up in GCP allow TCP connections at port 80. When I use `localhost` instead of `0.0.0.0` it's fine, but if I use `0.0.0.0`, it shows the following stack trace:

```
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/waitress/__init__.py", line 11, in serve
    server = _server(app, **kw)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/waitress/server.py", line 85, in create_server
    sockinfo=sockinfo)
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/waitress/server.py", line 183, in __init__
    self.effective_host, self.effective_port = self.getsockname()
File "/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages/waitress/server.py", line 299, in getsockname
    self.socketmod.NI_NUMERICSERV)

socket.gaierror: [Errno -3] Temporary failure in name resolution
```

This indicates that there is a DNS issue going on, but I'm unclear what it is. `0.0.0.0` indicates that it will try to connect for any IP address that it can. Any ideas what might be the issue?

Comment: What Linux distribution is this? What version of Waitress?

Comment: Ubuntu 18.04 and version "1.0.1-1" (that's what apt-get reports) for Waitress, which I installed with `sudo apt-get install python3-waitress`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a [bug](https://github.com/Pylons/waitress/issues/149) which was fixed in Waitress 1.0.2. You should upgrade to the latest available version, or file a bug report on Launchpad to request that Ubuntu backport the bug fix.

Comment: You're right, it works now!